python oop does not recognize command, why?
I am converting a function type app to an oop version, and ran into trouble. Here is my destilled problem code:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class createBlank():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self = Frame(master, bg='white')
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.Next_Button = Button(self, text="Next", font=helv18, command=self.doNext)
        self.Next_Button.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady=3)
        
    def doNext(self):
        print("Next!")

When I run it, I get: AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'doNext'
If I eliminate the command in building the Next_Button, I don't get an error message, and the section runs as intended, except for the button functionality.
I tried it with and without tk.Frame in the class argument, with and without super()init,
with and without leading.self's, nothing works. All I want is the button to function, even if it is only to print 'Next'

self = Frame(master, bg='white') - why are you doing that?

As pointed out in the comments, why do you do self = Frame(master, bg='white)? This is exactly what cause your code not recognize the doNext() action... Below is a working example:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class createBlank(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.parent = master
        super().__init__(self.parent, bg='white')
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
        helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.Next_Button = Button(self, text="Next", font=helv18, command=self.doNext)
        self.Next_Button.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady=3)
        
    def doNext(self):
        print("Next!")
        
        
root = Tk()

window = createBlank(root)
window.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

root.mainloop()

Actually, there isn't much differences between our codes, the only difference is that I inherit the tk.Frame() class and then initialize it with super().__init__().
If you have a valid reason (I wouldn't recommend it, though) to do something like self = XXX, then have a look at this question

By doing self = Frame(master, bg='white'), I assume you intended to make createBlank a Frame. You can achieve this by adjusting the inheritance:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class createBlank(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)  # Or use Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.Next_Button = Button(self, text="Next", font=helv18, command=self.doNext)
        self.Next_Button.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=3)

    def doNext(self):
        print("Next!")

root = Tk()
createBlank(root)
root.mainloop()

If, for any reason, you prefer not to use inheritance, you can use composition with a Frame and then append all other widgets of createBlank to it.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class createBlank:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.Next_Button = Button(self.frame, text="Next", font=helv18, command=self.doNext)
        self.Next_Button.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=3)

    def doNext(self):
        print("Next!")

root = Tk()
createBlank(root)
root.mainloop()



When I run it, I get: AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute
'doNext'

The problem can be fixed.
Don't use wildcard from tkinter import *
Use this import tkinter as tk. Then use this tk. prefix.
If you use master as a root. Then you use a prefix like self.parent for Frame widget instead of self
Snippet a small minor change:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

class createBlank():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.parent = tk.Frame(master, bg='white') # <==  change to `self.parent`
        self.parent.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.Next_Button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Next", font=helv18, command=self.doNext)
        self.Next_Button.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, pady=3) # use `tk.` prefix
        
    def doNext(self):
        print("Next!")

root = tk.Tk()
window = createBlank(root)
root.mainloop()

